# I am trying to pull H1 Tag

Tags: html

I have been searching online for awhile now.. I have a very datted php website. Which is currently uses graphics instead of H1 Tags..

I want to remove the images put H1 Tags for better SEO.

But I would like to display the Title from the h1 tag into the website page title.

ie.

```
<h1>Welcome To Website</h1>
```

To appear...

```
<head>
<title>Stackoverflow - Welcome To Website </title>
</head>
```

Note. There is over 150 pages so I cant manually change each page.
Note. Header is a separate file than the content pages.

Comment: You want it automatically or what? What's the problem?

Comment: Basicly whatever is in the H1 Tag I would like it to be added to the website Page Title with the website name..I would love to use wordpress but Im stuck fixing this old dated website.

Comment: Why don't you add it manually?

Comment: Because the content is a separate file than the header.php... Also theres over 150+ pages

Comment: You can make it a variable in header.php, and then just echo it on your pages. I don't see an easy automated solution unless you use JS, but JS won't help you with SEO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit 2

The closest thing I can come up with, is a Javascript method:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <head>
  <title> </title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
function updateTitle() {
    var title = document.getElementsByTagName("H1")[0];
    if (title) document.title = title.innerHTML;
}
  </script>
 </head>
 <body onload='updateTitle()'>

<h1>This Is The Title</h1>
 </body>
</html>
```

#### Sub-edit:

To add text in front of it to appear only in the page title:

Change this line:

```
if (title) document.title = title.innerHTML;
```

to:

```
if (title) document.title = "Text in front of " + title.innerHTML;
```

---

### Edit 1

Let's try this with sessions:

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['title'] = "Welcome to Website";
$title = $_SESSION['title'];
?>

<head>
<title><?php echo strip_tags($title); ?></title>
</head>

<body>

<h1><?php echo $title; ?></h1>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut at blandit elit. In ut leo eget leo aliquet dapibus a eu ligula. Vestibulum sed mi porta, lobortis lorem at, sodales ligula. In sapien dolor, tincidunt at volutpat ac, aliquet at nunc. Mauris rhoncus vel eros nec aliquam. Duis imperdiet fringilla lacus, non eleifend purus malesuada at. Fusce semper, metus eu laoreet aliquam, tellus enim mattis tellus, et accumsan elit velit vel risus. Ut sed lacus ut ligula ultrices rutrum et eget eros. In feugiat fringilla diam, semper pretium magna hendrerit vitae. Aliquam a ultrices urna. 

</body>
```

---

### Original answer

Use the [`strip_tags()`](http://www.php.net/strip_tags) function to strip the HTML tags.

```
<?php
$title = "<h1>Welcome To Website</h1>";
?>

<head>
<title>StackOverflow - <?php echo strip_tags($title); ?></title>
</head>

<body>

<?php echo $title; ?>

</body>
```